# Is this a natural way of asking someone to confirm their name? "Frank, was it?"

Tags: idiomatic-language

*Frank, was it? Listen, Frank...*

I believe I've heard something like this said. Is it natural? Is it asked for someone to confirm their name?

Comment: Yes, that is perfectly idiomatic and natural.  It is very informal, though.  More formal might be something like "I'm sorry, your name was Frank, is that correct?"